# How can I ensure this recylerview only adjusts when necessary?

Tags: java, android, logic, undo

I have a program where if the player enters 'hit' three times in a row the player gets three more throws. If they miss one throw out of the three it is the next player's turn after they have finished their third throw.

Player turns are ordered in a RecylerView.

The users are able to undo their previous actions, which correctly adjusts other stats.

I have a situation where if a player has finished their three throws with missing one it moves on to the next player, without the next player throwing the user decides to undo this action so the program brings the last row up to the top of the RecylerView.

The user undo's all previous throws for their turn. I'm testing with three in a row hit, +1 hit + two misses. This works fine. the problem arises when this player's stats are reduced to 0. The next player in line comes to the top but when I try to delete their stats it is moving another player to the top. I've been trying to fix this for hours, and identified that the problem lies in an if statement.

Here is the problem in GIF Form:

[image]

I need this if statement as you can see for the gif to remove the first player who was moved back to the top at the beginning of the undo action.  I tried putting a `boolean` in different places in the code to say 'The recyler view has only been adjusted - dont touch'

Here's where the problem lies:

```
 else if (!accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.get(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.size() - 1) && Integer.parseInt(amountThrown.get(0)) % 3 == 0 && !accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.isEmpty()) {
                previousAmountThrown = Integer.parseInt(amountThrown.get(amountThrown.size() - 1));
                amountThrown.set(amountThrown.size() - 1, String.valueOf(previousAmountThrown - 1));
                movePlayersInAdapter(apt_confirmedPlayers.size() - 1, 0); //Move to last element in adapter
                playerTurn = lastPlayerTurn;// AMOUNTTHROWN FOR P2 SHOWING AS MINUS 1 HERE IN INSPECTOR
                adjustListsToMatchTheAdapter(false);
                if(deleteTheHit) {
                    amountHitThisRound--;
                }
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(1); //Changes the items being moved to the correct color hides dart image
                if(!accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.isEmpty()) {
                    accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.remove(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.size() -1);
                    listOfThreeInARow.get(playerTurn).clear();
                    listOfThreeInARow.get(playerTurn).addAll(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow);
                } else {
                    listOfThreeInARow.get(playerTurn).clear();
                }
```

The code I want the program to reach whenever the first players stats have been deleted. This follows the above code in a else statement:

```
    else {
                Log.d("Result is empty", String.valueOf(!accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.isEmpty()));
                Log.d("value should be false", String.valueOf(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.get(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.size() - 1)));
                Log.d("value should be true", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(amountThrown.get(0)) % 3));
                if(deleteTheHit) {
                    previousAmountHit = Integer.parseInt(amountHit.get(0));
                    numToHit.set(0, String.valueOf(previousAmountHit));
                    amountHit.set(0, String.valueOf(previousAmountHit - 1));
                    amountHitThisRound--;
                }
                previousAmountThrown = Integer.parseInt(amountThrown.get(0));
                amountThrown.set(0, String.valueOf(previousAmountThrown - 1));
                if(!accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.isEmpty()) {
                    accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.remove(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow.size() -1);
                    listOfThreeInARow.get(playerTurn).clear();
                    listOfThreeInARow.get(playerTurn).addAll(accessPlayerHistoryThreeInARow);
                } else {
                    listOfThreeInARow.get(playerTurn).clear();
                }
```

*If this is too broad of a question for SO, please point me in the direction of where's more suitable*